# How to do a where clause across pattern matches

Tags: haskell

I can get a `where` clause to work across pattern matches a `case` statement:

```
updateHung :: Text -> Maybe Char -> Int
updateHung word got =
    let x = case got of
            Just l
                | elem l . unpack $ word -> pass
                | otherwise -> strike
            Nothing -> pass
            where
                strike = 1
                pass = 0
    in x
```

But when I try to do the same thing using a multipart function it doesn't work:

```
updateHung :: Text -> Maybe Char -> Int
updateHung word (Just l)
    | elem l . unpack $ word = pass
    | otherwise = strike
updateHung word Nothing = pass
    where
        strike = 1
        pass = 0
```

Is there some way to get this to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the working version, your `where` clause is indented misleadingly. You've indented it as though it were attached to the `case` statement, but in fact it is attached to the definition of `x`, and would be more clearly indented as

```
updateHung :: Text -> Maybe Char -> Int
updateHung word got =
    let x = case got of
          Just l
              | elem l . unpack $ word -> pass
              | otherwise -> strike
          Nothing -> pass
          where
            strike = 1
            pass = 0
    in x
```

A `where` clause is always scoped to a single *pattern*, across all the guards of that pattern. This is very important, because that allows it to use variables that were introduced by the pattern. For example, it might be useful for you to use `l` in the definition of `pass`, but that would make no sense if you could somehow have it scoped to the entire `case` statement.

If you want variables in scope for all of your patterns, you must bind those variables before starting to pattern match. Define a single equation for your function, and define variables in it, either with `let` or with `where`, and then do the rest of your logic in a `case` on a tuple of all your parameters, or just the ones you care about:

```
updateHung :: a -> Maybe Char -> Int
updateHung word got =
  let strike = 1
      pass = 0
  in case got of
     Just l
       | elem l . unpack $ word -> pass
       | otherwise -> strike
     Nothing -> pass
```

or

```
updateHung :: Text -> Maybe Char -> Int
updateHung word got =
  case got of
     Just l
       | elem l . unpack $ word -> pass
       | otherwise -> strike
     Nothing -> pass
  where strike = 1
        pass = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

[@amalloy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62927070/246886) explains how and why `where` clauses are scoped to a single *equation*, not a whole *definition*, and offers an alternative using `case`. But just to answer your narrower question, if you want to keep using the equational style, but also have shared local definitions in a `where` clause, you can use a local “worker” function scoped to the *same* `where` block as your auxiliary definitions, so they’re all in scope together:

```
updateHung = go
  where
    go word (Just l)
      | elem l $ unpack word = pass
      | otherwise = strike
    go word Nothing = pass

    strike = 1
    pass = 0
```

Then, as a simplification, you can lift the `word` parameter to `updateHung`, because it’s always matched the same way in `go`:

```
updateHung word = go
  where
    go (Just l)
      | elem l $ unpack word = pass
      | otherwise = strike
    go Nothing = pass

    strike = 1
    pass = 0
```

When the local definition is recursive and the outer definition just sets up its initial parameters, this is often referred to as the [worker–wrapper transform[ation]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Worker_wrapper), which can be beneficial to performance in two ways:

1. Sharing parameters like `word` that remain the same throughout the inner computation, rather than repeatedly passing them as arguments to recursive calls
2. Allowing the outer definition to be inlined to expose more optimisations (since GHC will generally not inline recursive functions).